# How does the poll function work in c?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am new to socket programming and I'm trying to figure out how poll works. So I made a little example program. The program seems to work as how I expect it to, but when I comment out the line that has `int dummy`  the `for` loop only runs one iteration when it's suppose to do ten. What I don't understand is how that variable has anything to do with the `for` loop. The program is suppose to print "timeout" after 3.5 secs and print "return hit" if there is input available.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <poll.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    char buf[10];
    int i;
    struct pollfd ufds[1];      
    ufds[0].fd = 0;
    ufds[0].events = POLLIN;
    int rv;
    int dummy;
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%i ", i);
        if((rv = poll(ufds, 2, 3500)) == -1) perror("select");
        else if (rv == 0) printf("Timeout occurred!\n");
        else if (ufds[0].revents & POLLIN) {
            printf("return hit\n");
            read(0, buf, 10);
        }   
        fflush(stdout); 
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if((rv = poll(ufds, 2, 3500)) == -1) perror("select");
                    ^
```

You are telling `poll` you have 2 file descriptors (2 pollfd structures) but you only have one. That's **undefined behavior** (you're tricking poll to tread into unallocated memory). Change that argument to 1.

Comment: BTW, the original poster should have read carefully the man page of `poll` e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll

Answer (score 2):

The change in behaviour when commenting-out `dummy` is likely because of changes to the stack that effect `ufds` and the fact you are passing the wrong `nfds` value into `poll()`.  You should also reset the values of `pollfd.revents` before the next call to `poll()`.